# What book(s) would you recommend for structuring and pricing Exotic Products?

Tags: option-pricing, derivatives, pricing, exotics, structured-finance

I've been looking for good books on structuring equity derivatives (Principal Protected Notes, Autocalls, Lookbacks, Reverse Convertibles etc). I only found ones that discuss mainly the theoretical aspect (stochastic calculus, arbitrage pricing theory etc) but would like something that talks mainly about the practical aspects of pricing these derivatives and how to actually structure them. For example: the actual Monte Carlo methods applied, the different algos used in production, the various models and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Exotic Options and Hybrids: A Guide to Structuring, Pricing and Trading*, Wiley, 2010. https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B003F8S7B8/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1 was quite interesting, and I think you can probably find it on the web somewhere.

Comment: Yes, that one is quite good for practical purposes.

Answer (score 2):

"Applied Quantitative Finance for Equity Derivatives" by Jherek Healy might be of interest to you though it's not focused specifically on exotics.

The sellside (especially French banks) should have primers on exotics though given they're effectively sales pitches, they might not have the detail you're looking for.

Comment: This sounds like an excellent new book on pricing! I'll probably get it. Regarding sell-side primers, I really liked the 1998 Salomon Smith Barney Exotic Equity Derivatives Manual (product description only, no pricing)

Answer (score 1):

Satyajit Das
Structured Products Volume 1: Exotic Options; Interest Rates and Currency (The Das Swaps and Financial Derivatives Library)

to volume 3

Comment: OP specified equity derivatives.

Comment: Volume 2 https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Structured+Products+Volume+2%3A+Equity%3B+Commodity%3B+Credit+and+New+Markets+%28The+Das+Swaps+and+Financial+Derivatives+Library%29%2C+3rd+Edition+Revised-p-9780470821671 has equities, but is not very deep. I don't think there was vol 3

Answer (score 1):

Since other answers already mentioned [Das vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470821663) and [vol 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470821671) ; and [Bouzoubaa and Osseiran](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470688033), I would like to add the good old:

- [Harry Kat. Structured Equity Derivatives: The Definitive Guide to Exotic Options and Structured Notes. Wiley (2001)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471486523) (not a very deep discussion of pricing, but good explanation of the product).
- [Marcus Overhaus, Ana Bermudez, Hans Buehler, Andrew Ferraris, Christopher Jordinson, Aziz Lamnouar. Equity Hybrid Derivatives. Wiley (2007)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471770582) - the focus is mostly on hybrids (equity and rates or equity and credit) but the pricing discussions are very good.